# git rebase conflict was caused by which commit

Tags: git

when I do git rebase master I get conflict sometimes. And sometimes it becomes very difficult to track down an issue even with error messages. It would be a real help if I could find out which commit git is trying to reapply and is causing conflict.

How can I find out which commit is causing the conflict?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118364/how-to-identify-conflicting-commits-by-hash-during-git-rebase

Answer (score 2):

Look in the conflicting file(s), the lines starting with `>>>>>>>` show the commit hash which caused the conflict.

Comment: I don't think you will find any SHA1 in a rebase conflict file (in a merge conflict file, yes, not in a rebase one)