# How to know if there is a git rebase in progress?

Tags: git, git-rebase

When I start a `git rebase -i`, I can issue commands like `git rebase --continue`, or `git rebase --abort`. Those commands only work if a rebase is in progress.

How can I know if there is a rebase in progress?

(I would greatly appreciate some details on how rebase works internally; what does git do to a repo that gives it the "rebase in progress" status,?)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Update 2021:

As I mentioned in "[`git stash` is slow on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318372/6309)", with [Git for Windows 2.19](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.19.0.windows.1) (Sept. 2018), `git stash` (and `git rebase`) are no longer script-only, but actually a binary compiled with `git.exe`.

[Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265521/timmmm)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67245016/6309) illustrates how it is still difficult to ascertain if a rebase is in progress.

That was discussed in the mailing list, leading to patch like "[`status`: `rebase` and `merge` can be in progress at the same time](https://public-inbox.org/git/7b2f5e37f4dca7cafb4d6ea5eebafc31e120a339.1542065154.git.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/)":

> Since `git rebase -r` was introduced, that is possible.
> But our machinery did not think that possible, and failed to say anything about the rebase in progress when in the middle of a merge.

There was a case of "rebase in progress" detection before that (2016), with "[`worktree.c`: check whether branch is rebased in another worktree](https://public-inbox.org/git/1461330096-21783-11-git-send-email-pclouds@gmail.com/)"

This function `find_shared_symref()` is used in a couple places:

> 1. in `builtin/branch.c`: it's used to detect if a branch is checked out elsewhere and refuse to delete the branch.
> 2. in `builtin/notes.c`: it's used to detect if a note is being merged in another worktree
> 3. in `branch.c`, the function `die_if_checked_out()` is actually used by "`git checkout`" and "`git worktree add`" to see if a branch is already checked out elsewhere and refuse the operation.
>
> In cases 1 and 3, **if a rebase is ongoing "HEAD" will be in detached mode**.
> `find_shared_symref()` fails to detect it and declares "`no branch is checked out here`", which is not really what we want.

---

Original answer: 2010

For one thing, **[there is a `ORIG_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)** in place during a rebase (but that is not limited to the rebase command)

But you can also look at the 2010 Git 1.7.0 **[`git-rebase.sh` script](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-rebase.sh)** itself (which is as "internal" as you can get ;) ).
Lines like those can give you another clue:

```
dotest="$GIT_DIR"/rebase-merge
test -d "$dotest" -o -d "$GIT_DIR"/rebase-apply || die "No rebase in progress?"
```

[sabgenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790359/sabgenton) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3244353):

- The folder `rebase-apply` seems to appear with `rebase`,
- but a folder `rebase-merge` shows up only with with `rebase -i`.

And [hippy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58678/hippy) also [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921409/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-git-rebase-in-progress/3921928?noredirect=1#comment75727179_3921928), in 2017, that:

> The coding guidelines discourage the usage of `-o` (see [`Documentation/CodingGuidelines`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69e6b9b4f4a91ce90f2c38ed2fa89686f8aff44f/Documentation/CodingGuidelines#L154-L164)), so the correct way [now (2017, but also since 2011, Git 1.7.6)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99de0640f2837d31f84d2889a770d936ae4394be) is:
>
> ```
> (test -d ".git/rebase-merge" || test -d ".git/rebase-apply") || die "No rebase in progress?"
> ```

[Jelaby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5128343/jelaby) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921409/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-git-rebase-in-progress/3921928?noredirect=1#comment80566125_3921928):

> ```
> (test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge)" || \
>  test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply)" )
> ```
>
> This correctly handles worktrees and unusual or non-standard layouts that don't have a `.git` directory, and also allows you to run this test from a subdir of the working directory.

That is because the [`git rev-parse --git-path <path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#git-rev-parse---git-pathltpathgt): does resolve "`$GIT_DIR/<path>`".

And [Elizandro - SparcBR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2942797/elizandro-sparcbr) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921409/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-git-rebase-in-progress/3921928#comment107357541_3921928):

> Could also redirect the error to null:
>
> ```
> (test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge)" || test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply) 2>/dev/null"
> ```

---

Git 2.6+  (Q3 2015) will print more information during a rebase:

See [commit 592e412](https://github.com/git/git/commit/592e412d0f02313fcab7c7264b4237c298539971), [commit 84e6fb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84e6fb9da95c1d2407fd2740336371f9604ef6d7) (06 Jul 2015), [commit 84e6fb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84e6fb9da95c1d2407fd2740336371f9604ef6d7) (06 Jul 2015), and [commit df25e94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df25e9475bbec86c5c8adaea1d515e7559607def), [commit 05eb563](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05eb5635537bac0494bfd8cf41fa5502e05b6fd6) (30 Jun 2015) by [Guillaume Pagès (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 178d2c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/178d2c7a7fdf0af639078963acfa6d56bad278ca), 03 Aug 2015)</sup>

> ## `status`: give more information during `rebase -i`

> `git status` gives more information during `rebase -i`, about the list of commands that are done during the rebase.
> It displays:
>
> - the last two commands executed and
> - the next two lines to be executed.
>
> It also gives hints to find the whole files in `.git` directory.

---

Trying and detect the *prompt* won't work with Git 2.26+, as shown in [commit 6d04ce7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d04ce75c4dd4bf0aeda7383c4d791daa049c98a)

"`git rebase`" has learned to use the merge backend (i.e. the machinery that drives "`rebase -i`") by default, while allowing "`--apply`" option to use the "`apply`" backend (e.g. the moral equivalent of "`format-patch piped to am`").
(The `rebase.backend` configuration variable can be set to customize.)

See [commit 10cdb9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10cdb9f38adaa16aad64403bc931405564523985), [commit 2ac0d62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ac0d6273fa6618e1a8783e07e2363b3abba1f2a), [commit 8295ed6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8295ed690bf1d458f80cffdc17d663eb3ba5162a), [commit 76340c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76340c8107ba8e658f9cc76d1d220bac2944d1f1), [commit 980b482](https://github.com/git/git/commit/980b482d28482c307648c3abbcb16ae60843c7ae), [commit c2417d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2417d3af7574adc1fb14f7df31b862aa9551e2e), [commit 6d04ce7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d04ce75c4dd4bf0aeda7383c4d791daa049c98a), [commit 52eb738](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52eb738d6b40bf8816727fcf7f39febc761ef0db), [commit 8af14f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8af14f08596197d53c40b71ed014b030956a12be), [commit be50c93](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be50c938dfc1555ea62df455a41138e41503b952), [commit befb89c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/befb89ce7c43a0bd0de11909951dd3015874e9db), [commit 9a70f3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a70f3d4ae673e02e78b1061fcc8fc01bc8d9276), [commit 93122c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93122c985a3671bd4e15b3dbc6b457c981eb8c23), [commit 55d2b6d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55d2b6d785da8c49d693d989c22f47622783903a), [commit 8a997ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a997ed132f7b8709d1752b64779566600345375), [commit 7db00f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7db00f0b3bc2c0bde616d45cf6e3a130e74e3024), [commit e98c426](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e98c4269c86019bfe057a91b4305f784365b6f0b), [commit d48e5e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d48e5e21da980c6d439655a1292d0332b341c7d1) (15 Feb 2020), and [commit a9ae8fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9ae8fde2eb0c00723d850ba23ea8401864fab83), [commit 22a69fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22a69fda197f78410190469bf0fcb51f6f69730f) (16 Jan 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8c22bd9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c22bd9ff9d4a355d3546181698307a797fd2bd2), 02 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### `git-prompt`: change the prompt for interactive-based rebases

> In the past, we had different prompts for different types of rebases:
>
> ```
> REBASE: for am-based rebases
> REBASE-m: for merge-based rebases
> REBASE-i: for interactive-based rebases
> ```
>
> It's not clear why this distinction was necessary or helpful; when the
> prompt was added in commit [e752019](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e75201963f6722ad84491c8f17dff8406ec0a198) ("Improve bash prompt to detect
> various states like an unfinished merge", 2007-09-30, Git v1.5.5-rc0), it simply added these three different types.
> Perhaps there was a useful purpose back then, but there have been some changes:
>
> - The merge backend was deleted after being implemented on top of the interactive backend, causing the prompt for merge-based rebases to change from `REBASE-m` to `REBASE-i`.
> - The interactive backend is used for multiple different types of non-interactive rebases, so the "`-i`" part of the prompt doesn't really mean what it used to.
> - Rebase backends have gained more abilities and have a great deal of overlap, sometimes making it hard to distinguish them.
> - Behavioral differences between the backends have also been ironed out.
> - We want to change the default backend from am to interactive, which means people would get "`REBASE-i`" by default if we didn't change the prompt, and only if they specified `--am` or `--whitespace` or `-C` would they get the "`REBASE`" prompt.
> - In the future, we plan to have "`--whitespace`", "`-C`", and even "`--am`"   run the interactive backend once it can handle everything the `am-backend` can.
>
> For all these reasons, make the prompt for any type of rebase just be "`REBASE`".

---

[Since Git 2.17 (March 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58698138/6309), you also have:

```
git rebase --show-current-patch
```

It shows the content of `.git/REBASE_HEAD` during an interactive rebase which can be paused during conflict.

Comment: shouldn't git-status tell you this?

Comment: As of git version 1.7.3.1, git status doesn't say anything about the rebase status.

Comment: However, [EasyGit](http://people.gnome.org/~newren/eg/)’s `eg status` [*does* tell you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12098177/578288).

Comment: Interpreting the `git-rebase.sh` code in this answer, Git knows there is a rebase in progress if, inside the `.git` folder at the root of the repo, either of the directories `rebase-merge` or `rebase-apply` exist.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane that sounds about right, and +1 on your answer with EasyGit.

Comment: Do you really need the dotest variable ?

Comment: @greg0ire probably not, it was just how the script was initially written.

Comment: thanks, I was just checking if I was missing something, as I intend to reuse this elsewhere...

Comment: The master link for `git-rebase.sh` now does not have the quoted code. VonC, please use [this link](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b0883aa6c77111e88496bd0afe073caf68ab9f99/git-rebase.sh) which is tag: v1.7.0-rc1. The coding guidelines discourage the usage of `-o` (see https://github.com/git/git/blob/69e6b9b4f4a91ce90f2c38ed2fa89686f8aff44f/Documentation/CodingGuidelines#L154-L164) so the correct way now is `(test -d ".git/rebase-merge" || test -d ".git/rebase-apply") || die "No rebase in progress?"`.

Comment: @hIpPy Thank you. I have updated this 7 years-old question accordingly, adding a link to the exact commit which made that change.

Comment: In Git 2.7 and maybe earlier, you can use something like `(test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge)" || test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply)"`. This correctly handles worktrees and unusual or non-standard layouts that don't have a .git directory, and also allows you to run this test from a subdir of the working directory.

Comment: @Jelaby Thank you, good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Could also redirect the error to null: (test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge)" || test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply) 2>/dev/null"

Comment: @Elizandro-SparcBR Interesting, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: How about .git/REBASE_HEAD ? It contains a hash. Could that also be reliable? It's similar to MERGE_HEAD, in the case of a git merge.

Comment: @Elizandro-SparcBR It is a marker, to indicate at what commit the rebase is at in case of conflict. I would therefore use `git rebase --show-current-patch` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---show-current-patch)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Is the 2021 update providing some new command or just adding additional information about git internals?
Is `(test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge)" || \
 test -d "$(git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply)" )` the recommended way?

Comment: `test -d ...` was the old answer. The 2021 update is to point out the answer is not as easy as using `git rev-parse` output. Tim's answer illustrates that.

Answer (score 24):

You can also check how such detection is done in [`__git_ps1` function in `contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob/1e6f5b22ad318446500fbd3b94b733eddd5b6414:/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#l377), which can be used for git-aware bash prompt:

```sh
                if [ -f "$g/rebase-merge/interactive" ]; then
                        r="|REBASE-i"
                        b="$(cat "$g/rebase-merge/head-name")"
                elif [ -d "$g/rebase-merge" ]; then
                        r="|REBASE-m"
                        b="$(cat "$g/rebase-merge/head-name")"
                else
                        if [ -d "$g/rebase-apply" ]; then
                                if [ -f "$g/rebase-apply/rebasing" ]; then
                                        r="|REBASE"
                                elif [ -f "$g/rebase-apply/applying" ]; then
                                        r="|AM"
                                else
                                        r="|AM/REBASE"
                                fi
                        fi
                fi
```

Answer (score 9):

There are some bad answers here. `git` doesn't really have a specification for how it should work so the only answer is "how does git do it?". The code is [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/142430338477d9d1bb25be66267225fb58498d92/wt-status.c#L1598):

```c
int wt_status_check_rebase(const struct worktree *wt,
               struct wt_status_state *state)
{
    struct stat st;

    if (!stat(worktree_git_path(wt, "rebase-apply"), &st)) {
        if (!stat(worktree_git_path(wt, "rebase-apply/applying"), &st)) {
            state->am_in_progress = 1;
            if (!stat(worktree_git_path(wt, "rebase-apply/patch"), &st) && !st.st_size)
                state->am_empty_patch = 1;
        } else {
            state->rebase_in_progress = 1;
            state->branch = get_branch(wt, "rebase-apply/head-name");
            state->onto = get_branch(wt, "rebase-apply/onto");
        }
    } else if (!stat(worktree_git_path(wt, "rebase-merge"), &st)) {
        if (!stat(worktree_git_path(wt, "rebase-merge/interactive"), &st))
            state->rebase_interactive_in_progress = 1;
        else
            state->rebase_in_progress = 1;
        state->branch = get_branch(wt, "rebase-merge/head-name");
        state->onto = get_branch(wt, "rebase-merge/onto");
    } else
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

It basically checks if these few files/directories exist (note `!stat()` means "does the file exist"). `am` is `git am` which is for applying patches from a mailbox which I doubt anyone except the Linux developers use.

- `rebase_in_progress`: `.git/rebase-apply && !.git/rebase-apply/applying || .git/rebase-merge && !.git/rebase-merge/interactive`
- `interactive_rebase_in_progress`: `.git/rebase-merge && .git/rebase-merge/interactive`
- `am_in_progress`: `.git/rebase-apply && .git/rebase-apply/applying`

I guess if you want to know if any kind of rebase/am is happening just check if `.git/rebase-apply` or `.git/rebase-merge` exist.

Comment: How should this be modified if `.git` is a file with a path to the actual git folder?

Comment: If you're in a worktree and `.git` is a file then you need to parse the file (e.g. it might contain `gitdir: /path/to/repo/.git/worktrees/worktreename`) and then check for `/path/to/repo/.git/worktrees/worktreename/rebase-apply` etc.

Answer (score 4):

If there’s an interactive rebase in progress, this will tell you where you are in the process:

```
$ cat .git/rebase-merge/done 
pick 786139e lrg
edit 668b8a6 ktio
$
```

Right now I’m editing the “ktio” patch in an interactive rebase.

If there’s no rebase going on, it will look like this:

```
$ cat .git/rebase-merge/done 
cat: .git/rebase-merge/done: No such file or directory
$
```

Answer (score 4):

From a bash command line:

```
ls `git rev-parse --git-dir` | grep rebase
```

That will return exit code 0 (success) if there is a rebase folder, and it will output the rebase folder to STDOUT. If you are *not* in the middle of a rebase, then it will output nothing and return non-0 exit code. So you could even do something like this:

```
ls `git rev-parse --git-dir` | grep rebase || echo no rebase
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have [EasyGit](http://people.gnome.org/~newren/eg/), `eg status` will tell you:

```
$ eg status
(Not currently on any branch.)
(YOU ARE IN THE MIDDLE OF A INTERACTIVE REBASE; RUN 'eg help topic middle-of-rebase' FOR MORE INFO.)
Changes ready to be committed ("staged"):
    modified:   .gitmodules
    renamed:    config_loader.rb -> code/config_loader.rb
Newly created unknown files:
    vendor/
(YOU ARE IN THE MIDDLE OF A INTERACTIVE REBASE; RUN 'eg help topic middle-of-rebase' FOR MORE INFO.)
```

In a colored terminal, the notification is very prominent:

[image: <code>eg status</code> middle-of-rebase demonstration screenshot]

(`eg help topic middle-of-rebase` displays the documentation “[How to resolve or abort an incomplete rebase](http://people.gnome.org/~newren/eg/documentation/topic-middle-of-rebase.html)”.)

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen it stated clearly, so here it is:

during rebasing process, if there is one under way, `git status` is now sufficient, as it gives information (for reference, I head smaple branches named `master` and `rbBr`):

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto 5f8e534
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick 1b7a450 BRANCH: another comment
No commands remaining.
You are currently rebasing branch 'rbBr' on '5f8e534'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both modified:   User.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

This is shown before resolving conflicts, after resolving conflicts it shows:

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto 5f8e534
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick 1b7a450 BRANCH: another comment
No commands remaining.
You are currently rebasing branch 'rbBr' on '5f8e534'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   User.java

PS C:\my_git_repos\learning_git> git rebase --continue                                                                                                                                                                                       [detached HEAD 9645135] BRANCH: another comment
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/rbBr.
```

Comment: True, but not applicable for a script: parsing/grepping the `git status` output would not be a good practice, as commented in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921409/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-git-rebase-in-progress/63480042#comment107912454_50492869

Comment: Good one. Just add `--porcelain` or `--porcelain=v2` to make it more suitable for automated scripts.

Answer (score -2):

I am using this command `is_rebase=$(git status | grep "rebasing" | wc -l)`

Comment: This is broken: if you have a dirty file that contains 'rebasing', it will print that you are rebasing even though you aren't.