# Gulp compiles during git-rebase causing rebase errors

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gulp, git-rebase, gulp-watch

When I pull rebase my code, git will start playing back the changes, causing my Gulp compile rules to fire. Every once in a while, this will cause the code to be in an inconsistent state that prevents pushing.

Consider a situation like this:

1. rebase to commit a
2. compile begins
3. rebase to commit b
4. compile for step 2 finishes
5. rebase fails

Does anyone have a strategy for avoiding this? I'm using git/gulp inside IntelliJ, but I'm hoping these someway to prevent this other than stopping the Gulp watcher before every single rebase/push.

Answer (score 1):

Git gives information about the status of rebases. See

[How to know if there is a git rebase in progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921409/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-git-rebase-in-progress)

Using Gulp you can easily use one of these methods to determine if a rebase is in progress, and if so, prevent the compilation from happening in your Gulp `watch` loop