# How to prevent commit in detached HEAD

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, git-detached-head

Why does git allow you to commit to a detached head? Is there any pre commit hook that can disable it?  What is the purpose?  Many new developers do this and I'd like to find a way to disable it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be only prevented by a local git `pre-commit` hook, so developers would need to create it. Add the `your-local-project/.git/hooks/pre-commit` file with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! git symbolic-ref HEAD &> /dev/null; then
  echo "You are in a detached head state! Commit has been blocked. (Use --no-verify to bypass this check.)"
  exit 1
fi
```

Make sure it's executable. [Credits go to svachalek](https://gist.github.com/svachalek/5437407)

Why should git prevent commiting in detached HEAD? Detached HEAD means *only* that there is no pointer to the repository state you are working on. It assumes that you know what you are doing.

I would rather investigate why *many developers* in your team enter this state? Maybe they apply some weird worklow?

Comment: While this will prevent commits to detached head, it will also interfere with (interactive) rebase operations. Internally, rebase uses detached heads to replay the commits.

Comment: Allowing rebases would require [detecting them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921409/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-git-rebase-in-progress) in the hook. However, I can hardly imagine a developer who does interactive rebase and is afraid of commits in detached HEAD at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Git uses this internally for many operations.  The detached HEAD mode simply gets you on the (one, single, special) anonymous branch, and the anonymous branch can be given a name later.

This is, for instance, how `git rebase` manages to copy the commits from their original chain to a new chain.  First it checks out the `--onto` target commit (`--onto` defaults to the `<upstream>`) using this detached HEAD mode.  Then, for each commit that is to be copied, it copies that commit (with `git cherry-pick` or something equivalent: the details vary depending on interactive vs non-interactive rebase, and if interactive, many more details).  Last, it moves the existing branch label so that it points to the final copied commit.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout $commit-sha1` can lead to a detached HEAD. So does `git checkout FETCH_HEAD`.  A detached HEAD could be considered as a branch without a name. If it does not confuse you, you could just ignore it. As @fracz said, you could prevent it by `pre-commit`. You could also make it a branch with a name with `git checkout -b some_name`. A `post-checkout` hook may help you to detect the detached HEAD state and make it a branch.

Comment: +1 for the idea of  branch creation in the `post-checkout` hook. However, it would have to create branches with random names which in turn would create a big mess over time.

Comment: @fracz Yes, random branch name is indeed a problem. We could use some logic to find a proper name but by contrast it's still a bit troublesome. So just ignore it or find the root cause and prevent it in advance. As I know, `repo sync` with no `repo start` can also lead to detached HEAD state if Repo is in use.

Comment: Creating the branch in the `post-commit` hook would avoid creating branches when the user doesn't actually want to commit anything.  See https://gist.github.com/ben-cohen/316f89c763e9d8a027335261a44c4954