# Prevent post-commit hook after cherry-pick

Tags: git, githooks

Is there a way to prevent running post-commit hook after cherry pick? I would like to run post commit hook specifically only after `git commit`. Or is there a way to figure out inside the hook that the commit has been cherry-picked? This is possible for [example for rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921409/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-git-rebase-in-progress), but that's a different case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved this inside the hook itself. I check the output of `git reflog -n 1`, which is something like `e06ca29a23 HEAD@{0}: cherry-pick: commit message`. It's not bulletproof, if you ammend the commit during cherry-pick, there is a new entry in reflog for the ammend, but apart from that, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For `git cherry-pick` the file seems to be [`CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9f6f3b6195a0ca35642561e530798ad1469bd41/path.c#L1483). `git` uses it in the same [sequencer](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9f6f3b6195a0ca35642561e530798ad1469bd41/sequencer.c#L2257) used for cherry-pick/rebase/revert. `git status` [uses it](https://github.com/git/git/blob/08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468/wt-status.c#L1641) to report "cherry-pick is in progress".

Comment: I tried your idea but it seems like the `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` disapear before the commit, for examplewhile resolving some conflict, I can se the file, but when I run  `git cherry-pick --continue` with the following `post-commit` checking for the file existance like this `[[ -f "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD" ]] && echo "Cherry-Picking, Skip..." || "Post committing"`, I still get "Post committing".

Comment: I see the same behavior, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` doesn't exist any more when hook is run.