# Git compare "base" version with "theirs" version of a conflicted file?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Given a conflicted file `foo.txt`, how to tell `git diff` to show changes between the base version of the file and "their" version of the file?

I can see each of the versions via `git show :1:foo.txt` or `git show:3:foo.txt` - is there a simple way to compare the two versions?

Comment: This link shows how to view the patch that failed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118364/how-to-identify-conflicting-commits-by-hash-during-git-rebase  --ie, it explains how to see the "theirs" patch.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
git diff :1:foo.txt :3:foo.txt
```

More info at [man gitrevisions](https://gitirc.eu/gitrevisions.html); look for `:[<n>:]<path>`.

Comment: git must have introduced this syntax somewhere between today and the time I asked the question, thanks for the good news :)

Comment: This syntax has been available for many years. Just to be sure I tried it out in a rather ancient version (1.5.5) from April 2008 and it sure works. :)

Comment: I'd swear I tried that, so either I made some stupid typo or it was broken in a particular version. I guess I'll never know :)

Comment: To save some typing: `function gdf13 { git diff ":1:./$1" ":3:./$1"; }`

Comment: Could anyone please point me to the documentation of this syntax for `git diff` and `git show`, i.e. `:1` and `:3`? I can't see it in documentation of `git diff` and `git show`

Comment: [man gitrevisions](https://gitirc.eu/gitrevisions.html) look for `:[<n>:]<path>`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply type `git diff` and it will show only the conflicts.

Further reading: [Advanced Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging)

Notice the `--base` and `--theirs` arguments for `diff`

Comment: I only want to see "their" changes. When the chunks are large it is rather hard to infer that from the output of `git diff` alone.

Comment: If you mean that it's hard to see you might wanna use `git difftool` and then select your favourite diff ui, for instance meld.

Comment: Thanks, I know this (and also the diff3 conflict style option). I am just looking for a quick way to see "their" changes on a file.

Comment: As to `--base` and `--theirs` arguments for diff: can they be used to compare `--base` with `--theirs`? This would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry I got you wrong. `git diff --base --theirs` seems to change nothing in the output.

Comment: @ThomasRawyler link is dead