# View git diff from individual parents

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

Say, I've been presented with a merge conflict, and I managed to fix it, but haven't marked as resolved (i.e. I haven't done `git add` conflicted files yet). At this point, I can do `git diff` and I'll be shown how the resultant file differs from each parent, in a combined diff format.

All good so far. Now I wanted to separately inspect how resultant file differs from individual parent. Sure, for a merge conflict involving 2 parents (cherry-pick, rebase etc.), I can use `git diff --ours` or `git diff --theirs`, but how do I extend this to more parents?

In other words, if I get conflict from 3 parents, is it possible to view individual diffs w.r.t each parent?

Also, my discovery of `--ours` and `--theirs` was rather serendipitous; I couldn't find their usage documented in a diff context.

Comment: You could `diff` a working tree with any particular commit in the repo. Is this enough for you?

Comment: If file is still marked as 'C (conflicted)' you may need to manually `git reset` it, and then you can `git diff` it with any version you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show parents of uncommitted merge in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590740/show-parents-of-uncommitted-merge-in-git)

Comment: Just an advice. Try using "rebase" instead of merge, whenever possible. It will make your life a lot easier...

Answer (score 2):

If

```
git diff :1:foo.txt :3:foo.txt
```

does not do what you want, I guess you have to do

```
git ls-files -u
```

and the use `git show $sha1 > $sha1.txt` to create some temporary files and compare those.

See also: [Git compare "base" version with "theirs" version of a conflicted file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488365/git-compare-base-version-with-theirs-version-of-a-conflicted-file)